# Conditional probability of distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I found this question on the internet:

Police conduct random breath tests on drivers during a busy night in the city. 3% of drivers drink and drive at the time. $X$ is is the number of drivers that police need to test to get the first case of drinking and driving. $Y$ is the number of drivers tested to get 3 such cases.

If police have not found any cases of drinking and driving on their first 5 tests, how can you calculate the conditional probability that they cannot find any cases in their next 5 tests?

So far I can see that $X$ is a geometric distribution, and $Y$ is a negative binomial,  and to calculate the conditional probability is to use this formula:

$$
P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B).
$$

But I am not sure how to link this formula with these distributions to solve the above question. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the police has not found any case after $i$-th test, it means the case will be found if the police conduct the test more than $i$, or we can say $X>i$

Hence, you need to calculate

\begin{eqnarray*}
\Pr(X>10|X>5)=\frac{\Pr(X>10,X>5)}{\Pr(X>5)}=\frac{\Pr(X>10)}{\Pr(X>5)}
\end{eqnarray*}

As I remember, geometric distribution has memoryless property, so the answer should be same if you just calculate $\Pr(X>10-5)=\Pr(X>5)$. But, maybe I am wrong. Calculate both of them to make it doubly sure I think

No need to use $Y$